# How to access Vercel serverless functions locally using Vite?

Tags: webpack, serverless, vite, vercel

I found many solutions to make Vercel serverless functions work with Vite on prod (I got that working using rewrites), but I can't use them locally.

As far as I can see, the routes created from `vercel dev` that uses Vite to compile the app, won't enable pointing to the functions and will try to go straight into react-router-dom routes.

Is there a workaround? Should I spin up serverless functions separately?